# React Native why would my array size increase without push

Tags: arrays, react-native, state

```
for(var i = 0; 2*i < this.state.showMember.length; i++) {
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <TouchableHighlight key={"home "+this.state.members[2*i]}
            underlayColor= { this.state.showMember[2*i] ? this.state.memberColors[(2*i)% this.state.memberColors.length] : Colors.hideScheduleColor }
            style={{
                backgroundColor: this.state.showMember[2*i] ? this.state.memberColors[(2*i) % this.state.memberColors.length] : Colors.hideScheduleColor}}
            onPress={()=>{
                let newShowMember = this.state.showMember;
                newShowMember[2*i] = !newShowMember[2*i];
                this.setState({showMember: newShowMember});
            }}>
            <Text>{ this.state.members[2*i] }</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight key={"home "+this.state.members[(2*i)+1]}
            underlayColor= { this.state.showMember[(2*i)+1] ? this.state.memberColors[((2*i)+1)% this.state.memberColors.length] : Colors.hideScheduleColor }
            style={{
                backgroundColor: this.state.showMember[(2*i)+1] ? this.state.memberColors[((2*i)+1) % this.state.memberColors.length] : Colors.hideScheduleColor}}
            onPress={()=>{
                let newShowMember = this.state.showMember;
                newShowMember[(2*i)+1] = !newShowMember[(2*i)+1];
                this.setState({showMember: newShowMember});
            }}>
            <Text>{ this.state.members[(2*i)+1] }</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
}
```

Above is a snippet of code from my app. 
I am trying to make the `TouchableHighlight` backgrounds to change color whenever they are clicked. In doing so, I have 3 arrays:

- `showMember` : stores information of whether a member's name would be shown or not
- `memberColors` : stores designated color for each member
- `members` : stores the name of members

So I'm setting my `TouchableHightlight`s' background and underlay colors to change according to the `showMember` value for that member, and have the `onPress` functions to change the `showMember` value for that member.

Since I heard that it is not "react way" to directly modify the state values, so I am creating a temp array with altered boolean value for the selected member, then setting the state of `showMember` to this temp array.

However, from the logs, I found that creating this temp array will append a new entry every time I click on any of the members. I am confused about this because I am just doing `let newShowMember = this.state.showMember` and this will copy the array from the state value and add a new entry to it.

Why would this strange behavior be occurring and what are some ways to get around it?

Comment: Your code is very hard to read. Please remove unnecessary style props and code (e.g. console outputs).

Comment: @Mukeyii shortened and left out parts of the code that I thought were not necessary

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple fix:

```
for(var i = 0; 2*i < this.state.showMember.length; i++) {
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}} key={`home ${i}`}>
        <TouchableHighlight 
            underlayColor= { this.state.showMember[2*i] ? this.state.memberColors[(2*i)% this.state.memberColors.length] : Colors.hideScheduleColor }
            style={{
                backgroundColor: this.state.showMember[2*i] ? this.state.memberColors[(2*i) % this.state.memberColors.length] : Colors.hideScheduleColor}}
            onPress={()=>{
                let newShowMember = this.state.showMember;
                newShowMember[2*i] = !newShowMember[2*i];
                this.setState({showMember: newShowMember});
            }}>
            <Text>{ this.state.members[2*i] }</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight
            underlayColor= { this.state.showMember[(2*i)+1] ? this.state.memberColors[((2*i)+1)% this.state.memberColors.length] : Colors.hideScheduleColor }
            style={{
                backgroundColor: this.state.showMember[(2*i)+1] ? this.state.memberColors[((2*i)+1) % this.state.memberColors.length] : Colors.hideScheduleColor}}
            onPress={()=>{
                let newShowMember = this.state.showMember;
                newShowMember[(2*i)+1] = !newShowMember[(2*i)+1];
                this.setState({showMember: newShowMember});
            }}>
            <Text>{ this.state.members[(2*i)+1] }</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
}
```

I was giving keys to inner components(`TouchableHighlight`s) and for some reason they were all getting their keys for when `i` was 3, the terminating condition for the loop on my set of data for testing purposes. By setting keys for the exterior `View` component, I was able to resolve this issue.